# Fast way to tokenize a string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

I tried to use `strtok_r` but its slow.

Now I have a c string as `"root.ahmed.andre"` and a fixed separtor as `'.'`

How would I write a faster search tokenizer using c ?

```
for (int i = 0;test[i] != 0; i++)
{
    if (test[i] == '.')
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: Too slow for what?  `strtok_r()` does in-place modification of the string -- it's hard to get much faster than that.

Comment: j_random_hacker, how would I tokenize the string using the for loop above ?

Comment: So instead of answering my question ("Too slow for what?"), you just ask (a variation of) your original question again.

Comment: `i < test[i] != '0'` in the for loop should be `test[i] != 0`.

Comment: What makes you think `strtok_r` is slow ?

Comment: @mch, fixed that bug, thanks

Comment: @MichaelWalz I just want to use a fixed separtor, and just a simple for loop for tokenizer the string

Comment: no, you did not fix the bug, you only fixed one part of the bug.

Comment: @mch what else is problem please help :) ?

Comment: `i < test[i] != 0` vs `test[i] != 0`. Something like `a<b<c` does not do what you think.

Comment: Start with the source code for `strtok_r` and modify the code to use a single delimiter.  http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/msp430-libc/ci/master/tree/src/string/strtok.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about `strtok_r`, but `strtok` is probably the fastest way to tokenize a string. Perhaps you were doing it wrong? Maybe that is why it appeared slow for you.

Here is how you tokenize a string in C...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
    char  string[] = "root.ahmed.andre";
    char *token = strtok (string, ".");

    while (token) {
        // Do what you want with the token here...
        puts (token);

        // Get the next token
        token = strtok (NULL, ".");
    }
}
```

And just for the sake of argument, the code below tokenizes your string 1,000,000 times and displays how long it took to do so. For me, it took 90 ms. That's blazing fast.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int
main (void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    long int       start;
    long int       end;
    int            i;

    // Get start time in milliseconds
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    start = (tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec / 1000);

    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        char  string[] = "root.ahmed.andre";
        char *token = strtok (string, ".");

        while (token) {
            token = strtok (NULL, ".");
        }
    }

    // Get end time in milliseconds
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    end = (tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec / 1000);

    // Print execution time in milliseconds
    printf ("\nDone in %ld ms!\n\n", end - start);

    return 0;
}
```